# Microsoft Acess retrieving count rows in a table

Tags: sql, ms-access

In Acess how i can select a number of rows in a table from some number count that a user specifies.

For example, this DB is prompting to a user introduces a given number, p.e: 10, and the table retrives 10 records, given a table from 100 or 10000 records

Comment: You're looking for SQL keyword `TOP`

Comment: But how do i make the connection between the user number and that TOP?

Comment: The same way you add parameters to any query. Do some searching on OleDbCommand and OleDbParameter .

Comment: Pretty sure you can't use a parameter to specify the `TOP` amount in Access.

Answer (score 1):

Use dynamic SQL:

```
Dim rs  As DAO.Recordset
Dim Top As Integer

Top = 10  ' User input.

Set rs = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Select Top " & Str(Top) & " * From YourTable")
```

Comment: May I ask why `Str(Top)` and not just `Top`?

Comment: `Str` explicitly casts the value to a string. Not needed, but makes it clear what you are doing.